# How to get/install/activate a Broadcom 4312 wl driver in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my Lenovo G550 laptop. It has a Broadcom 4312 Wireless LAN adapter which is not working.

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
```

How do I fix it? How can I see what drivers are being used? I've downloaded what I think is the driver from the Broadcom site but have no idea how to get it installed.

Please keep in mind that I'm completely new at this Linux stuff.

Comment: Please run lspci -nn and edit your question to add your wireless card details.

Answer (score 6):

The Broadcom 14e4:4315 needs this:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```